# Does choice of sound card effect timidity's performance?

Tags: midi, sound-synthesis, soundcard

I'm working on web application which will be using timidity++ to converting midi file into wav file. I know that it will not work without sound card, so I must have server with it. My question is: Is the used sound card will impact to the speed of generating wav files? And if the answer to my question is yes, what should I pay attention when I buy sound card. What sound cards what can you recomend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sound card should definitely *not* impact the speed of synthesis, especially if you are doing it offline. In fact, software such as [MrsWatson](https://github.com/teragonaudio/MrsWatson) can use a VST instrument plugin to synthesize MIDI events to an audio file and do not require any sound hardware at all.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of MrsWatson*